# how to load some of the files in a dir and monitor new file in that dir in spark streaming without missing?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have one hdfs dir, which contains many files:

```
/user/root/1.txt
/user/root/2.txt
/user/root/3.txt
/user/root/4.txt
```

and there is a daemon process which add one file per minute to this dir. (e.g., 5.txt, 6.txt, 7.txt...)

I want to start a spark streaming job which load 3.txt, 4.txt and then detect all the new files after 4.txt.

Please pay attention that because these files are large, processing these files will take a long time. So if I process 3.txt and 4.txt before launching  the streaming task, maybe the 5.txt, 6.txt will be produced into this dir during processing 3.txt and 4.txt. And when the streaming task start, 5.txt and 6.txt will be missed for processing because it will only process from new file(from 7.txt)

I'm not sure if I describe the problem clearly, if you have any question, please ask me

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

according to the doc api : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

```
def
fileStream[K, V, F <: InputFormat[K, V]](directory: String, filter: (Path) ⇒ Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[K], arg1: ClassTag[V], arg2: ClassTag[F]): InputDStream[(K, V)]
```

Create a input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for new files and reads them using the given key-value types and input format.

we could set the filter function to filter the file < 4.txt

and then set the "newFilesOnly" to false